# How to combine two csvs/tab delimited into one csv with php?

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have two files one is a tab delimited and one is a csv which is comma seperated and they both get uploaded and I need to combine them into one csv thats sorted...here is my code so far

```
$txt = glob('files/*.txt*');
$csv = glob('files/*.csv*');
$test = array();
if (($handle = fopen($csv[0], "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $test[$c][] = $data[$c];
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

if (($handle = fopen($txt[0], "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
          $test[$c][] = $data[$c];
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

the test array has the full array of both but i am running into a few problems first the $test array is like this

```
[0] => Array
       (
           [0] => Edit
           [1] => y
           [2] => y
           [3] => y
           [4] => y
           [5] => y
           [6] => y
           [7] => y
           [8] => y
           [9] => y
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Event
        [1] => Carolina Panthers PSL
        [2] => Florida
        [3] => Carolina Panthers PSL
        [4] => Apple
        [5] => Carolina Panthers PSL
        [6] => Carolina Panthers PSL
        [7] => Carolina Panthers PSL
        [8] => Carolina Panthers PSL
        [9] => Carolina Panthers PSL
        [10] => Carolina Panthers PSL
[2] => Array
     (
         [0] => Venue
         [1] => Bank of America Stadium 
         [2] => Washington Mutual 
         [3] => Bank of America Stadium 
         [4] => Apple Inc
         [5] => Bank of America Stadium 
         [6] => Bank of America Stadium 
         [7] => Bank of America Stadium 
         [8] => Bank of America Stadium 
         [9] => Bank of America Stadium 
         [10] => Bank of America Stadium 
         [11] => Bank of America Stadium 
         [12] => Bank of America Stadium
```

How do i create a new csv with everything but i need to sort by event name and this format for the test array seems off..any ideas what im doing wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the column names are on the first line of your file this should work:

```
$txt = glob('files/*.txt*');
$csv = glob('files/*.csv*');
$test = array();
$headers = array();
if (($handle = fopen($csv[0], "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    if (empty($headers)) {
      for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        $headers[$c] = $data[$c];
      }
    }
    else {
      $line = array();
      for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        $line[$headers[$c]] = $data[$c];
      }
      $test[] = $line;
    }
  }
}

if (($handle = fopen($csv[0], "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    $line = array();
    for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
      $line[$headers[$c]] = $data[$c];
    }
    $test[] = $line;
  }
}
```

That should give you an array like

```
[0] => Array
(
       [Edit] => y
       [Event] => Carolina Panthers PSL
       [Venue] => Bank of America Stadium,
       ...
[1] => Array
(

       [Edit] => y
       [Event] => Florida
       [Venue] => Washington Mutual ,
...
```

Then you can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) on the array to sort it by the `Event` key with a custom callback. See the docs page for that function for loads of examples, or try this:

```
function my_sort($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a['Event'], $b['Event']);
}
usort($test, 'my_sort');
```

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of the code below should work for you I believe.

```
<?php
// Opens files
$file1 = glob("files/*.txt");
$file1 = $file1[0];
$f1 = file("files/$file1");
$file2 = glob("files/*.csv");
$file2 = $file2[0];
$f2 = file("files/$file2");

// Creates counter and storage arrays for each column
$c = 0;
$col1 = array();
$col2 = array();
$col3 = array();

// goes through each of the first files lines
foreach ($f1 as $row => $data)
{
    // changes tabs for commas
    $data .= str_replace("\t",",",$data);
    // splits the string into the 3 columns in different arrays
    list($col1[$c],$col2[$c],$col3[$c]) = explode(",",$data);
    $c++;
}

foreach ($f2 as $row2 => $data2)
{
    if ($row2 != 0)
    {
        // splits the string into the 3 columns in different arrays
        list($col1[$c],$col2[$c],$col3[$c]) = explode(",",$data2);
        $c++;
    }
}
// Sort by column 2, the event
asort($col2);

// First column is headers
$realOutput = $col1[0].",".$col2[0].",".$col3[0]."\n";

// Add them in sorted order by column 2
foreach ($col2 as $key => $val)
{
    if ($key != 0)
        $realOutput .= $col1[$key].",".$col2[$key].",".$col3[$key]."\n";
}

echo $realOutput;

?>
```

Comment: I dont have the names of the files though...i have only the extension

Comment: also how do i get the final csv to print the headers also...any idea...both files have the exact same headers

Comment: I added the glob command to find one TXT and one CSV file. I also added a couple of if statements to only put the headers in once and then to display them only at the top of the file.

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED** to account for columns not being in the same order, and avoid column headers being present in sorted data. This still relies on column headers being the same (including identical case). Also fixed `SORTDESC` (should be `SORT_DESC`)

```
$txt = glob('files/*.txt*');
$csv = glob('files/*.csv*');
$rows = $events = array();

// Get data into rows, not columns
if (($handle = fopen($csv[0], "r")) !== FALSE) {
    // Get column headers
    $headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
    // Get rest of rows
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $row = array();
        foreach ($data as $k => $v) $row[$headers[$k]] = $v;
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

if (($handle = fopen($txt[0], "r")) !== FALSE) {
    // Get column headers
    $headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        $row = array();
        foreach ($data as $k => $v) $row[$headers[$k]] = $v;
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

// Prepare the sort column for array_multisort()
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
  $events[$key] = $row['Event'];
}

// Sort it
array_multisort($events, SORT_DESC, $rows);

// Open the output file
$outFile = fopen('outfile.csv','w');

// Put the column headers back
fputcsv($outFile, array('Edit','Event','Venue'), ',');

// Write the data
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  fputcsv($outFile, $row, ',');
}

// Close the file
fclose($outFile);
```